# A recommended book for Curved Geometry

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, resource-recommendations, education

I want to study Einsteins General Theory of Relativity, but before i start reading about it can anyone of you recommend some good books about Curved Geometry? since i will need it to understand the first part.

Comment: John Lee - "Introduction to Riemannian Manifolds"

Comment: Gravitation - Misner, Thorne, Wheeler

Comment: I think that every good book on general relativity has what you need to know about curved geometry in order to understand GR, you can look in the big books recommendation thread